# Plist with Different Strings options

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist

Is there a way to add string in a plist file from source code?. I want to add two more columns, but when I try to do this Its shows that code is been corrupted. Is there any option to pass more values?. The working code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Title 1</string>
    //here i want to add one more string(value) how to do so?

    <key>subtitle</key>
    <string>Subtitle 1</string>
    <key>image</key>
    <string>image1.png</string>
</dict>
```

what i want in plist is ...

`Key`  `Type`  `Value`  `value`  `value`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string> 1</string>
    <string> 2 </string> 
     <string> 3</string>
    </dict>
 </Plist>
```

Comment: which is the value that you want to add?, can you include the code you are using the modify the file?

Comment: like I suppose to add one more value say image and when i add string it gets corrupt

Comment: if you give us more details about the columns that you need to add, and about how you're doing this to get a corrupted file, will be easiest to get the solution to your problem

Comment: check now question ..what i exactly want

Comment: as @Zaphod say, for doing this you has to create an array and put the values inside this array. In a dictionary you can not assign more than one object to a key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately dictionaries use the Key/Value paradigm, that means only one value for a given key. But you can set an array containing two strings, for example:

```
<key>title</key>
<array>
    <string>Title 1</string>
    <string>Title 2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: it will give the drop down option in the plist . but i want code to give more than one value isnt it possible?

Comment: I'ma afraid not, the only way to set 2 values for one key is to use an array.

Comment: ok thanks is there any other way , like I have a excel file with multiple values, I thought that plist would work for me. but not now.is there any other way to store and display in table view

Comment: I don't understant why the use of an array bothers you. In fact, when you store it this way, you can still display it in a Table View. Instead of getting a string, you get an array containing strings. It's mush more easy to use cause you gain all the abilities of an array : counting values, sorting, etc.

Comment: ya man thanks! that works for me. but now getting error in displaying in tableview . i can display only one key values...please check this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723600/display-plist-into-uitableview