# Display Plist into UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist

I want to display `Plist` to the `UITableView` .By my below code I can display one key values that is `list of states`. but i want to display all the values of three tables.

```
- (id)readPlist:(NSString *)fileName 
{
NSData *plistData;
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
id plist;

NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"];
plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath]; 

plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
if (!plist) {
NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file '%s', error = '%s'", [localizedPath UTF8String],      [error UTF8String]);

}

return plist;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[[self readPlist:@"sample"] objectForKey:@"ListOfStates"] count];

}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[[self readPlist:@"sample"] objectForKey:@"ListOfStates"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;}
```

MY output comes only `listofkeystates` values

[image: enter the image] 
is it also possible to display `key` name with `values`

Comment: What do you really want? Three sections within the values of each tables, or an agregation of the three tables?

Comment: It would help if you could show the code for readPlist: and the output you currently get.

Comment: @Zaphod sorry its not error .but i am able to display only key values of listofstates that is selangor,terengganu,gfh,johor and melaka only

Comment: @PeterM please check the question now.i have given readplist code ...and my output is  only key values of listofstates that is selangor,terengganu,gfh,johor and melaka only

Comment: @SameSungVsIphone I think that jjv360's answer may be what you are looking for.  But I did see that you use `propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:` which has been deprecated.  Apple suggests using `propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`

Comment: @jjv360's solution is the easiest to list the three tables.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use table sections...

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSDictionary* dict = [self readPlist:@"sample"];
    return dict.allKeys.count;
}

-(NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary* dict = [self readPlist:@"sample"];
    return [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary* dict = [self readPlist:@"sample"];
    NSString* key = [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[dict valueForKey:key] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary* dict = [self readPlist:@"sample"];
    NSString* key = [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[dict objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just try to get data in `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` and then use it in `UITableView`

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

and use tableValue with its name like bellow...

```
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"ListOfStates"]; 
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

i hope this help you..

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : Corrected some typo mistakes

The idea

1. Loading plist in a dictonary
2. optional : sort it (!)
3. create the array of data for each section
4. create the array of section

Then implement the following things

1. viewDid load -> load the plist file in a dictionary, create an array of the sections and a dictionary of the data
2. numberOfSectionsInTableView -> the number of sections. In your case the number of keys
3. numberOfRowsInSection -> the number of rows of each section
4. titleForHeaderInSection -> for each section, the title of the section
5. cellForRowAtIndexPath -> the data of all row
6. sectionIndexTitlesForTableView -> the array that holds all you sections names. In your case all the keys

assuming you have a property called mySections and a property called myData
also assuming you use storyboard with standard cell with recycle identifier "Cell"

```
   @synthesize mySections
   @synthesize myData        

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //LOADING THE PLIST FILE

        //Create a string representing the file path
        NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"yourFilename" ofType:@"plist"];

        //Load the file in a dictionnary
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        self.myData = dict;

       //SORTING THE DICTIONARY    
       NSArray *dicoArray = [[self.myData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
          return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
      }];

      self.mySections = dicoArray;
    }

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       //Return the number of sections.
       return [self.mySections count];
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
       NSArray *dataInSection = [self.myData objectForKey:key];
       return [dataInSection count];
  }

  -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
    }

  -(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return self.mySections;
   }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *dataForSection = [self.myData objectForKey:key];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dataForSection objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: :-) hope it helps. Perhaps there are some typo mistakes. If you have questions just ask.

Comment: ya ur code is not working for me... :( first time I am trying to code in Plist ..not able to understand your code... what would be the mycode?

Comment: it should, it is a general code ;-) what error message do you get ?

Comment: thanks that working.but when i tap it to down it gets crash.i am unable to add scroll view in this..how to do that?

Comment: Do you use storyboard ? If yes, simply add a tableview controller. Directly a tableview controller not a viewcontroller to which you add a table view. Scroll is automatically present in tableview controller no need to add something. Perhaps show me the error message you get when you scroll to be able to help you.

Comment: sorryy i cant explain here..and its not been solved .plz give me your mail id .i mail you .you will get better vision

Comment: We should go to chat, comments are not here for that. By the way editing your question is possible. Click edit at the bottom of your question, add "EDIT" at the bottom and put a picture or error messages you get so that we can help you.